# beanshell jdbc connection, class loading

Tags: jdbc, beanshell

i want to connect to a hsqldb in beanshell script.

i had problems while loading class, i wrote it before and it was replied.

the code looks like that:

```
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
            getClass("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance();
            conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/testdata/tdb","SA","");
            System.out.println("Connection established");
    }
```

and i am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/testdata/tdb
```

and i tried to register Driver too but i didn't worked

```
DriverManager.register(getClass("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance())
```

this code works already in java (instead of getClass() using Class.forName())
what does beanshell need anymore to work this code?

Thanks,
Bilal

Comment: To exclude one and other, how about just a `new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver();` line?

Comment: I have also found this problem. I suspect it is something to do with the way the DriverManager getConnection method compares the classloader class name with the class that has been registered. The DriverManager class loading logic looks a little interesting, there is a native call in there...

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on this ,  there was no way to dynamically load JDBC classes as opposed to other types of objects, and instead,  I now use Runtime exec to call the command line program for the DB .  Also , beanshell has a "exec()" method.

Luckily, all I needed was to run scripts against the DB rather than actually interact with the DB , and so this works for me.

Also, the reason JDBC wont load for you is because Beanshell sometimes will load its own classloader (instead of the default classloader).  This happens especially if you try to dynamically load jars inside the Beanshell script.  If you put your jdbc.jar into Javasoft/ext directory, in that case I believe it will get into the default classloader.  Also, if your Beanshell script is careful enough [not to trigger the new classloader](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/classpath.html), that may work as well.  In other words, dont call "addClassPath" in your script, among other things.